# Crash when running on device

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am new to Android programming
and I try to learn it and take sample sample applications on the git * ub site, I have tried to resolve some errors in the application and after compiling the application is able to run, but the problem that arises when I open the details from the application post, the error is like this

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.newsagni/com.app.newsagni.ActivityPostDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2550)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5615)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.app.newsagni.ActivityPostDetails.displayPostData(ActivityPostDetails.java:190)
    at com.app.newsagni.ActivityPostDetails.onCreate(ActivityPostDetails.java:98)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6362)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    ... 9 more
```

The following listings from

ActivityPostDetails.java
https://pastebin.com/h56LUx2T

activity_post_details.xml
https://pastebin.com/hwYpza37

Can you help me overcome this error

Comment: You probably will need a `try-catch` to check if values (for `TextView`s) isn't empty then, set `TextView` values. Here, error comes from one of those values which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `TextView` with an id of "date", so Android cannot find the `TextView`. Therefore you get a NPE when trying to work with it. Add the `TextView` to your activity and you should be good to go.

Comment: Other `TextView`s are in `include_post_content` layout tho..

Comment: so i must add TextView with an id of "date" at ActivityPostDetails ?

Comment: @Mohsen Then the poster should post that file. Also, a simple findById should not require a try/catch. If you find yourself with errors being thrown when finding a TextView then it's setup improperly.

Comment: I learned from this application https://github.com/DebotHaxor/Agnihothram-News